# Replacing Longer Sentence With Word Count

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to figure out how to replace longer sentence (5 or more words) with the word count.

```
s = ['Two heads are better than one', 'Time flies', 'May the force be with you', 'I do', 'The Itchy and Scratchy Show', 'You know nothing Jon Snow', 'The cat ran']
```

If I do this:

```
numsentences = [len(sentence.split()) for sentence in s]

print(numsentences)
```

I get the word count. But I don't know how to get the entire list to show up where the sentences with 4 or less words come up, whilst the sentences with 5 or more words get printed by their word count.

I then tried something like this:

```
sn = []
for sentence in s:
    num if len(sentence.split(i) > 2)
```

but I am obviously not on the right track.

I need to get something like:

```
s = [6, 'Time flies', 6, 'I do', 5, 5, 'The cat ran']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```py
output = [string if len(string.split(' ')) < 5 else len(string.split(' ')) for string in s]
```

Output:

```
[6, 'Time flies', 6, 'I do', 5, 5, 'The cat ran']
```

Comment: So why the '  ' in len(string.split(' '))?

Sorry for the additional questions! I am only just learning and want to understand.

Comment: @Noob3000 Words in a sentence are separated by a ' ' (space) so that is the delimiter I am using to split the string. For example `"hello world".split(' ')` would give `['hello', 'world']`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do this by creating two lists.

First create a list of word counts, and then iterate through both the sentences and the word counts at the same time using `zip`. You can choose to include the value from one list or the other based on your condition.

```
sentences = [
    'Two heads are better than one',
    'Time flies',
    'May the force be with you',
    'I do',
    'The Itchy and Scratchy Show',
    'You know nothing Jon Snow',
    'The cat ran'
]

word_counts = [len(sentence.split(' ')) for sentence in sentences]
reduced_sentences = [
    sentence if word_count < 5 else word_count
    for sentence, word_count in zip(sentences, word_counts)
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use map() to extract the number of words from each sentence, and zip() to combine these word counts (`n`) with the original strings (`o`), then chose between the two in a list comprehension:

```
s = ['Two heads are better than one', 'Time flies', 
     'May the force be with you', 'I do', 
     'The Itchy and Scratchy Show', 'You know nothing Jon Snow', 
     'The cat ran']

r = [ [o,n][n>4] for o,n in  zip(s,map(len,map(str.split,s)))]

print(r)
[6, 'Time flies', 6, 'I do', 5, 5, 'The cat ran']
```